# How to iterate through a set of input with array

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I having a group of input with id like below

```
writing[size][1]
writing[size][2]
writing[size][3]
writing[size][4]
```

**I am using below code to iterate but failed**

```
$('input[id^="writing[size][]"]').each(function(){

});
```

How do I iterate through them using each()?

I have tried another set of input without array like

```
radio_1
radio_2
radio_2
```

I use below code to successfully iterate them but not input with array

```
$('input:radio[id^="radio_"]').each(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the attribute starting with selector, specify only the part of the attribute vaule that is shared between all the elements which is `writing[size]`, when you add `[]` at the end none of the name attributes starts with `writing[size][]` so no element is selected.

```
$('input[id^="writing[size]"]').each(function(){

});
```

```js
$('input[name^="writing[size]"]').each(function(i) {
  this.value = i;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="writing[size][1]" />
<input name="writing[size][2]" />
<input name="writing[size][3]" />
<input name="writing[size][4]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , simple and easy to understand , I'm just wondering that this kind of iterator consider a feature from css or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can also try to convert this to array and iterate through it using for loop.

```
var arr = $('input[id^="writing[size]"]').toArray();
```